# Laravel 5.2 Validation in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have no view for this controller.I want to use Laravel validation to check variables. and show custom errors by returning string in controller.(I dont use view, blade, session,... I just return string)

```
    if(strlen($username) < 4) return '{"r": "US","msg": "username is short"}';
    if(strlen($username) > 64) return '{"r": "UL","msg": "username is long"}';
    if(preg_match("/(\S*\d+\S*[[:alpha:]]+\S*)|(\S*[[:alpha:]]+\S*\d+\S*)/", $password)) return '{"r": "P","msg": "wrong password"}';
    if(strlen($name) > 32) '{"r": "N","msg": "wrong name"}';
    if(strlen($address) > 200) '{"r": "A","msg": "wrong address"}';
```

I want something like this:

```
    'username' => 'required|min:4|max:64|unique:users|regex:/[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|min:8',
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Validator` facade to validate any request in your controller. You can also extend this with your own messages.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|min:4|max:64|unique:users|regex:/[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|min:8',
],
[
    'email.required' => 'Email is required',
    'username.unique' => 'Username is taken'
]);
```

You can even decide what to do if this validation fails

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->route('register')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Now, if you need access to these error messages instead, you can do:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->errors();
}
```

Now you have access to the error messages you defined, and the default ones if not overridden.

Comment: Tanx. but how can I understand which variable has error or what error is this?